# How to play audio file of format wav in android webview?

Tags: android

This is my code: mp3 format file plays without any error, but wav format brings MediaPlayer error(1,-1):

```
try {
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setDataSource("h*.wav");
        player.prepare();
        player.start();} catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12481491/1815624

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make a reference to [Android supported media-formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)